# How to refer to sub-pattern in flex?

Tags: c++, flex-lexer

I use to program in `ocaml`, which includes a flex-equivalent tool: `coamllex`. It permits me to refer to sub-pattern in a whole patter as below:

```
(subpattern1 as sp1)subpattern2...
```

In action, I can refer to `subpattern1` with `sp1`. Does flex support such mechanism? I have not found it in documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Flex does not support any such mechanism.